# How does minted work from a point of LaTeX-User?

Tags: highlighting, minted, sourcecode

The package [`minted`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/minted) is one of the most famous package for highlighting source code. But how does it work?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The package [`minted`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/minted) based on two pillars. The TeX-pillar [`fancyvrb`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancyvrb) and the external pillar [`pygments`](http://pygments.org/download/). In a very simple speech you can say `minted` combines the verbatim ability of `fancyvrb` with the great highlighting of source code by `pygments`.

The basic procedure of `minted` can be described with the following steps:

1. Write everything of the environment in an external file with the extension `.pyg`
2. Run the tool `pygmentize` on the generated file and create a new one with the extension `.out.pyg`(BTW: This step is the reason for using `shell-escape`)
3. Input the new file `.out.pyg`

Let us use a simple example.

```
% arara: pdflatex: { shell: true }
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\begin{document}
\begin{minted}{c}
/* Hello World program */
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
    printf("Hello World");

}
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

Related to the three steps above the following is done:

1. A new file is generated `\jobname.pyg`

   ```
   /* Hello World program */
   #include<stdio.h>
   main()
   {
       printf("Hello World");

   }
   ```
2. A new file `\jobname.out.pyg` is generate with the following contents

   ```
   \begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\\\{\}, ]
   \PY{c+cm}{/* Hello World program */}
   \PY{c+cp}{\PYZsh{}include\PYZlt{}stdio.h\PYZgt{}}
   \PY{n}{main}\PY{p}{()}
   \PY{p}{\PYZob{}}
       \PY{n}{printf}\PY{p}{(}\PY{l+s}{\PYZdq{}Hello World\PYZdq{}}\PY{p}{);}
   \PY{p}{\PYZcb{}}
   \end{Verbatim}
   ```
3. The new file is included and the result will be:

   > [image]

---

Let us go more in detail.

In step 2 you see that every string is highlighted by the command `\PY`. This command has two mandatory arguments. The first one says how to highlight and the second one what to highlight. The kind of highlighting is depending on the used style. How the style is used, is related to the frontmatter. In our case [`latex.py`](https://bitbucket.org/birkenfeld/pygments-main/src/2ba9b53c87eeed24f7c5d2895ca27e637bca40a1/pygments/formatters/latex.py?at=default). The style files can be found [here](https://bitbucket.org/birkenfeld/pygments-main/src/2ba9b53c87ee/pygments/styles/?at=default).

For a LaTeX user it's easier to understand LaTeX commands instead of any python language. So let us take the example above.

Create a new file named e.g. `testpyg.pyg` with the contents above:

```cpp
/* Hello World program */
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
    printf("Hello World");
}
```

Now go to the terminal and run the following command (the same is done by `minted`)

```
pygmentize -l c -O full -f latex -F tokenmerge -o testpyg.tex testpyg.pyg
```

After this step you have a new tex-file with shows all definitions which can be manipulated. The relevant code is:

```
\makeatletter
\def\PY@reset{\let\PY@it=\relax \let\PY@bf=\relax%
    \let\PY@ul=\relax \let\PY@tc=\relax%
    \let\PY@bc=\relax \let\PY@ff=\relax}
\def\PY@tok#1{\csname PY@tok@#1\endcsname}
\def\PY@toks#1+{\ifx\relax#1\empty\else%
    \PY@tok{#1}\expandafter\PY@toks\fi}
\def\PY@do#1{\PY@bc{\PY@tc{\PY@ul{%
    \PY@it{\PY@bf{\PY@ff{#1}}}}}}}
\def\PY#1#2{\PY@reset\PY@toks#1+\relax+\PY@do{#2}}

\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@gd\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.63,0.00,0.00}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@gu\endcsname{\let\PY@bf=\textbf\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.50,0.00,0.50}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@gt\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.27,0.87}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@gs\endcsname{\let\PY@bf=\textbf}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@gr\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{1.00,0.00,0.00}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@cm\endcsname{\let\PY@it=\textit\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.25,0.50,0.50}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@vg\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.10,0.09,0.49}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@m\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.40,0.40,0.40}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@mh\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.40,0.40,0.40}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@go\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.53,0.53,0.53}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@ge\endcsname{\let\PY@it=\textit}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@vc\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.10,0.09,0.49}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@il\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.40,0.40,0.40}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@cs\endcsname{\let\PY@it=\textit\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.25,0.50,0.50}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@cp\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.74,0.48,0.00}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@gi\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.63,0.00}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@gh\endcsname{\let\PY@bf=\textbf\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.00,0.50}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@ni\endcsname{\let\PY@bf=\textbf\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.60,0.60,0.60}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@nl\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.63,0.63,0.00}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@nn\endcsname{\let\PY@bf=\textbf\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.00,1.00}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@no\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.53,0.00,0.00}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@na\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.49,0.56,0.16}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@nb\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.50,0.00}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@nc\endcsname{\let\PY@bf=\textbf\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.00,1.00}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@nd\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.67,0.13,1.00}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@ne\endcsname{\let\PY@bf=\textbf\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.82,0.25,0.23}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@nf\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.00,1.00}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@si\endcsname{\let\PY@bf=\textbf\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.73,0.40,0.53}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@s2\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.73,0.13,0.13}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@vi\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.10,0.09,0.49}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@nt\endcsname{\let\PY@bf=\textbf\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.50,0.00}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@nv\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.10,0.09,0.49}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@s1\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.73,0.13,0.13}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@sh\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.73,0.13,0.13}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@sc\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.73,0.13,0.13}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@sx\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.50,0.00}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@bp\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.50,0.00}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@c1\endcsname{\let\PY@it=\textit\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.25,0.50,0.50}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@kc\endcsname{\let\PY@bf=\textbf\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.50,0.00}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@c\endcsname{\let\PY@it=\textit\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.25,0.50,0.50}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@mf\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.40,0.40,0.40}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@err\endcsname{\def\PY@bc##1{\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\fcolorbox[rgb]{1.00,0.00,0.00}{1,1,1}{\strut ##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@kd\endcsname{\let\PY@bf=\textbf\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.50,0.00}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@ss\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.10,0.09,0.49}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@sr\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.73,0.40,0.53}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@mo\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.40,0.40,0.40}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@kn\endcsname{\let\PY@bf=\textbf\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.50,0.00}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@mi\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.40,0.40,0.40}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@gp\endcsname{\let\PY@bf=\textbf\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.00,0.50}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@o\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.40,0.40,0.40}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@kr\endcsname{\let\PY@bf=\textbf\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.50,0.00}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@s\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.73,0.13,0.13}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@kp\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.50,0.00}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@w\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.73,0.73,0.73}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@kt\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.69,0.00,0.25}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@ow\endcsname{\let\PY@bf=\textbf\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.67,0.13,1.00}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@sb\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.73,0.13,0.13}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@k\endcsname{\let\PY@bf=\textbf\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.50,0.00}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@se\endcsname{\let\PY@bf=\textbf\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.73,0.40,0.13}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@sd\endcsname{\let\PY@it=\textit\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.73,0.13,0.13}{##1}}}

\def\PYZbs{\char`\\}
\def\PYZus{\char`\_}
\def\PYZob{\char`\{}
\def\PYZcb{\char`\}}
\def\PYZca{\char`\^}
\def\PYZam{\char`\&}
\def\PYZlt{\char`\<}
\def\PYZgt{\char`\>}
\def\PYZsh{\char`\#}
\def\PYZpc{\char`\%}
\def\PYZdl{\char`\$}
\def\PYZhy{\char`\-}
\def\PYZsq{\char`\'}
\def\PYZdq{\char`\"}
\def\PYZti{\char`\~}
% for compatibility with earlier versions
\def\PYZat{@}
\def\PYZlb{[}
\def\PYZrb{]}
\makeatother
```

Based on this information it was possible to create special solutions for e.g. [Emphasise a particular keyword in minted](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/182528/emphasise-a-particular-keyword-in-minted)

Comment: My understanding is that [minted v2.0](https://github.com/gpoore/minted) will do away with some (all?) writing to external files; you might have to revise your answer when that new version gets officially released.

Comment: @Jubobs: Indeed. I will update my answer later.

Comment: I do like your answer, though. Concise but informative.

Comment: @Jubobs: I studied `minted v2.0` and there is no difference in the algorithm. `minted v2.0` has some extra feature for saving the files but this don't change the run of `pygmentize`

Comment: I've read a few posts by the new maintainer (see [this one](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/125992/21891)) suggesting that he has added some "caching support". However, I haven't studied `minted 2.0` myself, so I'm not sure what he's referring to.

Comment: @Jubobs: The new feature `cache` stores all minted-files (the raw file and the out-file) in a separate folder. So only unchanged and new `minted`-environments are compiled by `pygmentize`. This will improve the compilation speed specially for huge projects.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for adding details. Much appreciated.